How to properly backup docker repository using n3dr?
I try to use n3dr tool (https://github.com/030/n3dr) to make backup of self hosted docker repository in Nexus 3 OSS.
In my nexus 3 oss I have 3 docker repository:

docker-repo1 with port 8444
docker-repo2 with port 8445
docker-repo3 with port 8446
docker-group (docker-repo1 and docker-repo2) with port 8447

In documentation written I should use
n3dr repositoriesV2 --backup --dockerHost https://nexus.host --dockerPort 8444 -n nexus.host
But I get some issues with this

when use flag --backup there is making backup of all nexus without needed docker repo
when use flag --backup with --n3drRepo docker-repo-name then downloaded only manifests without images

As I see there is docker repositories support. And I expect (work fine with other repository types) that I can make a backup copy of the repository so that I can later transfer it to another server.
Maybe someone has encountered similar behavior and knows how to make a backup of the docker repository?

In general, after several days of research, this utility does not quite fit the described task. In the end, I decided to use a simple bash script that pulls the image into the local registry, re-tag, pushes it into the new registry
